# Magento 2.2.5- SOAP-ERROR Parsing WSDL

Tags: magento2, soap, magento-2.2.5, web-services, wsdl

Every time I run this script. I get an error.
I placed this file in the root directory of my magento.

> soapexample.php:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$wsdlurl = 'https://www.chemcopharmacy.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1';

$token = 'u46losnl6ia01ctmxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //access token


$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token]]; 
$context = stream_context_create($opts); //$arguments = $serviceArgs = 
$serviceArgs = array('searchCriteria'=> 
    array('filterGroups' => 
        array ('filters' =>
            array('field' =>'increment_id',
                  'value' => '000000002' , 
                  'condition_type' => 'eq')
            )
     ) ); 
 $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlurl);
 $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2); 
 $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
 $result = $soapClient->salesOrderRepositoryV1GetList($serviceArgs);
```

//array('searchCriteria' => $serviceArgs)); //$result = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById(array('customerId' => 1));

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing 
WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.chemcopharmacy.com/soap/default? 
wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1' : failed to load external entity 
"https://www.chemcopharmacy.com/soap/default? 
wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1" in 
/var/www/html/chemcopharmacy/vendor/zendframework/zend- 
soap/src/Client/Common.php:33 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/html/chemcopharmacy/vendor/zendframework/zend- 
soap/src/Client/Common.php(33): SoapClient- 
>SoapClient('https://www.che...', Array) #1 
/var/www/html/chemcopharmacy/vendor/zendframework/zend- 
soap/src/Client.php(1070): Zend\Soap\Client\Common->__construct(Array, 
'https://www.che...', Array) #2 
/var/www/html/chemcopharmacy/vendor/zendframework/zend- 
soap/src/Client.php(1245): Zend\Soap\Client->initSoapClientObject() #3 
/var/www/html/chemcopharmacy/vendor/zendframework/zend- 
soap/src/Client.php(1156): Zend\Soap\Client->getSoapClient() #4 
/var/www/html/chemcopharmacy/soapexample2.php(29): Zend\Soap\Client- 
>__call('salesOrderRepos. in 
/var/www/html/chemcopharmacy/vendor/zendframework/zend- 
soap/src/Client/Common.php on line 33
```

**What I have done?**

- I have edited the `/etc/hosts` file and added the `MY.IP.ADDRESS DOMAIN.COM`
- I have also set necessary setting in php.ini files for soap like

  *extension=php_soap.dll;
  extension=php_openssl.dll;*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the `SOAP Web Services` on my local host and it was working fine. The reason why the `Magento 2` was not able to give a response to the request was because it was not able to verify `SSL Certificates` enabled on the site.

The way I resolved it was to allow self signed `SSL verification`:

```
$opts = [
    'http' =>
     [
         'header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token
        ],
'ssl' => [
    'allow_self_signed' => true , 
    'verify_peer' => false, 
    'verify_peer_name' => false]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

I hope it helps. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to fix the  **failed to load external entity** issue
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/SOAP-Error-Failed-to-load-external-entity/m-p/38906#M917

Adding my snippet

```
$wsdl = 'http://m2.local.com/soap/?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1';
    $client = $this->soapClient->create($wsdl, array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));

    $token = $client->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken(array("username"=>"test", "password"=>"test"));

    $opts = [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer'=>false,
            'verify_peer_name'=>false
        ],
        'http' => [
            'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '. $token->result
        ]
    ];

    $params = [
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    ];

    $wsdlUrl = 'http://m2.local.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=quoteCartRepositoryV1';
    $soapClient = $this->soapClient->create($wsdlUrl, $params);

    $soapResponse = $soapClient->__getFunctions();
    var_dump($soapResponse);
```

Where the SoapClient is Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\ClientFactory

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163636)

Comment: hi Jai 

Edited my answer