# Magento2.3.2 Soap API issue

Tags: error, magento2.3.2, soap-api

Magento2.3.2 Soap API issue

**Code**:-

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$wsdlurl = 'https://domain.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1';
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';//access token


$opts = [
    'http' =>
     [
         'header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token
        ],
'ssl' => [
    'allow_self_signed' => true , 
    'verify_peer' => false, 
    'verify_peer_name' => false]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

//$context = stream_context_create($opts); //$arguments = 
$serviceArgs = 
array('searchCriteria'=> 
    array('filterGroups' => 
        array ('filters' =>
            array('field' =>'increment_id',
                  'value' => '000000032' , 
                  'condition_type' => 'eq')
            )
     ) ); 
 $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlurl);
 $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2); 
 $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
 $result = $soapClient->salesOrderRepositoryV1GetList($serviceArgs);
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

**Error**:-

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://domain.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://domain.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1"
>   in vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php:33 Stack
>   trace: #0 vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php(33):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('http://domain.com....', Array) #1
>   vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1070):
>   Zend\Soap\Client\Common->__construct(Array, 'https://domain.com....',
>   Array) #2 vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1245):
>   Zend\Soap\Client->initSoapClientObject() #3
>   /vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1156):
>   Zend\Soap\Client->getSoapClient()
>   Zend\Soap\Client->__call('salesOrderRepos...', Array) #5 {main} thrown
>   in vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php on line 33

Comment: are you working on server or localhost..

Comment: both I have run the script on local but I have to debug  live and local url

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247628/magento-2-2-5-soap-error-parsing-wsdl